# OpenCV 3.0.0 Mat.push_back for vector line

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, opencv3.0

I want to procedurally build an `OpenCV` `Mat` line by line using the `push_back` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    Mat matrix(1,3,CV_8UC1);
    vector<unsigned char> line(3,1);
    matrix.push_back(Mat(line,true).t());
    return 0;
}
```

This returns the following error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (DataType<_Tp>::type == type() && cols == 1) in push_back, file /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 1071 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:1071: error: (-215) DataType<_Tp>::type == type() && cols == 1 in function push_back
```

I've guaranteed the types are equal by calling `type()` for each matrix and I could use `push_back(Mat(line,true))` (no matrix transposing), but the result was an added column

```
[1;
1;
1;]
```

The error seems to imply that I can only add elements column by column(`cols == 1` bit), but the method description says it adds elements to the bottom of the matrix (implying it adds lines)

Is there any workaround to this situation, or that's the way is has to be?

Comment: http://code.opencv.org/issues/4340

Comment: also, rather use a Vec3b (or Vec3f) to store your line data (hmm btw, doesn't it take 4 elements to store a line ? like x,y,dx,dy ?)

Comment: Thank you for the link, @berak, maybe you could post it as an answer, since it's a bug. I am not aware it takes 4 elements to store a line. I could do it element by element and it would take 3 arguments (y, x and the value). I'll try Vec3b and that procedural transposition mentioned.

Comment: wait a second, - how are you storing your line ? x,y will be positive integers, but i.e. dx dy or angle might be non integer and non positive, so unsigned char will be a bad choice for storage. prefer float here, i guess

Comment: @berak values can be stored elementwise with `matrix.at<float>(column,row)=value;`, but the main point of the question is to store line by line using the `push_back` function. I'll use my main type to CV_32F, but this does not alter the core of the question: pushing back vectors. Doing it in two lines `Mat line_m(line,true)` and then `line_m=line_m.t()` solved my issue, I suggest you post that as answer including your first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by berak in the bug report link(http://code.opencv.org/issues/4340), doing it in two lines solves the issue as needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    Mat matrix(1,3,CV_8UC1);
    vector<unsigned char> line(3,1);

    Mat line_m(line,true);
    line_m=line_m.t();

    matrix.push_back(line_m);
    return 0;
}
```

result via `cout<<matrix<<endl;`

```
[0 0 0;
 1 1 1]
```